# Display the preference dialog without going to the preference screen

Tags: android, android-preferences

I want to display the preference dialog without going to the preference screen. Want to implement this in a text editor where the user clicks on the font selection button and the dialog pops up for the user to select the custom font but am not able to achieve the same. Here is my code...!

```
package com.utils;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.preference.DialogPreference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;

public class FontPreference extends DialogPreference implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener
{
    // Keeps the font file paths and names in separate arrays
    private List< String >    m_fontPaths;
    private List< String >    m_fontNames;

    // Font adaptor responsible for redrawing the item TextView with the appropriate //font.
    // We use BaseAdapter since we need both arrays, and the effort is quite small.
    public class FontAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
      private List< String >    m_fontPaths;
      private List< String >    m_fontNames;

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return m_fontNames.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position)
        {
            return m_fontNames.get( position );
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position)
        {
            // We use the position as ID
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent )
        {
            View view = convertView;

            // This function may be called in two cases: a new view needs to be created,
            // or an existing view needs to be reused
            if ( view == null )
            {
                // Since we're using the system list for the layout, use the system inflater
                final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                            getContext().getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );

                // And inflate the view android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice
                // Why? See com.android.internal.app.AlertController method createListView()
                view = inflater.inflate( android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, parent, false);
            }

            if ( view != null )
            {
                // Find the text view from our interface
                CheckedTextView tv = (CheckedTextView) view.findViewById( android.R.id.text1 );

                // Replace the string with the current font name using our typeface
                Typeface tface = Typeface.createFromFile( m_fontPaths.get( position ) );
                tv.setTypeface( tface );

                // If you want to make the selected item having different foreground or background color,
                // be aware of themes. In some of them your foreground color may be the background color.
                // So we don't mess with anything here and just add the extra stars to have the selected
                // font to stand out.
                tv.setText( m_fontNames.get( position ) );
            }

            return view;
        }
    }

    public FontPreference( Context context, AttributeSet attrs )
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder( Builder builder )
    {
        super.onPrepareDialogBuilder(builder);

        // Get the fonts on the device
        HashMap< String, String > fonts = FontManager.enumerateFonts();
        m_fontPaths = new ArrayList< String >();
        m_fontNames = new ArrayList< String >();

        // Get the current value to find the checked item
        String selectedFontPath = getSharedPreferences().getString( getKey(), "");
        int idx = 0, checked_item = 0;

        for ( String path : fonts.keySet() )
        {
            if ( path.equals( selectedFontPath ) )
                checked_item = idx;

            m_fontPaths.add( path );
            m_fontNames.add( fonts.get(path) );
            idx++;
        }

        // Create out adapter
        // If you're building for API 11 and up, you can pass builder.getContext
        // instead of current context
        FontAdapter adapter = new FontAdapter();

        builder.setSingleChoiceItems( adapter, checked_item, this );

        // The typical interaction for list-based dialogs is to have click-on-an-item dismiss the dialog
        builder.setPositiveButton(null, null);
    }

//  //Expose the protected onClick method
//    void show() {
//        onClick();
//    }

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
    {
        if ( which >=0 && which < m_fontPaths.size() )
        {
            String selectedFontPath = m_fontPaths.get( which );
            Editor editor = getSharedPreferences().edit();
            editor.putString( getKey(), selectedFontPath );
            editor.commit();

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my preference.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:key="first_category"
        android:title="First Category" >
        <com.utils.FontPreference
            android:key="fonts"
            android:summary="Select Font"
            android:title="Change Fonts" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: Have you ever succeeded in what you were trying to accomplish? I'm currently trying to do the same—is it possible?